# UI Sortable не перемещается, если блок имеет высоту 0

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько блоков с итемами. Пытаюсь релизовать перенос итемов из блока в блок, но возникла проблема. Если высота одного из блоков равно 0, то туда элемент просто нельзя вставить. Как решить подобную проблему?

Вот код sortable:

```
$('.tasks-content-block').sortable({
            connectWith: '.tasks-status-items-block',
            items: '.component-task-item',
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            placeholder: "component-card-task-placeholder"
}).disableSelection();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы пробовали задавать фиксированное значение для блоков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас данный блок, фактически, не имеет высоты, следовательно перенести его вы не сможете.

*Попробуйте задать блокам минимальное фиксированное значение, например с помощью `min-height`*.

Воссоздать ваш пример не смог, но я привел свой.

Я попробую объяснить на примере:

В примере:

1. Ячейки перемещаются.
2. У пятой серой ячейки отсутствует текст намеренно, чтобы символы не увеличили высоту блока, но текст подразумевается('Item 5'). Высота блока равна `0px`, то есть блок, фактически, отсутствует, а также не кликается.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Handle empty lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; padding: 0px; width: 143px}
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li {margin: 5px; padding: 0px; width: 120px; border: 0px}
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
$( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "ul"
});
 
$( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "ul",
  dropOnEmpty: false
});
 
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
</ul>
 
<br style="clear:both">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Теперь если добавить `min-height = 150px` -> `#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li {margin: 5px; padding: 0px; width: 120px; border: 0px, min-height: 150px;}`, все ячейки отобразятся и будут функциональны:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Handle empty lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; padding: 0px; width: 143px}
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li {margin: 5px; padding: 0px; width: 120px; border: 0px; min-height: 150px}
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
$( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "ul"
});
 
$( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "ul",
  dropOnEmpty: false
});
 
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
</ul>
 
<br style="clear:both">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

*Или поступить хитро, если вам нужна высота блока `0 px`, тогда можно установить `padding` размером `1 px`, а высоту блока не изменять. Блок будет почти не виден, но кликабелен*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Handle empty lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; padding: 0px; width: 143px}
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li {margin: 5px; padding: 1px; width: 120px; border: 0px}
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
$( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "ul"
});
 
$( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "ul",
  dropOnEmpty: false
});
 
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
</ul>
 
<br style="clear:both">
 
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я это итак понимаю. Смысл в том, что мне нужно сделать функционал именно с высотой 0px.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS Предложил еще один вариант, надеюсь, поможет

Comment: @Sire IMPACTUS ещё один вариант решения, который я приложил, возможно, поможет вам